# Como hacer un trigger al insertar un dato

Tags: sql, sql-server

quería saber como hacer para crear un trigger que modifique un campo de una tabla al insertar. Por ejemplo teniendo mi tabla Articulos:

```
CREATE TABLE Articulos
(
    CodArt_A CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    DescArt_A varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    StockArt_A int DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    PrecioUnitAr_A Decimal (8,2) DEFAULT '0,00' NOT NULL,
    ActivoArt_A bit DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL,
    CodProv_A CHAR (10) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_ARTICULOS PRIMARY KEY (CodArt_A),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ARTICULOS_PROVEEDORES FOREIGN KEY (CodProv_A) REFERENCES Proveedores(CodProv_Pr)
)
GO
```

Quisiera hacer un trigger que modifique el stock al insertar.

Intente haciendo esto pero se que no funciona.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_CONSULTA6
ON DetalleFacturas 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN 
    
    UPDATE Articulos SET StockArt_A = StockArt_A - inserted.CantArt_DF FROM Articulos INNER JOIN inserted on inserted.CantArt_DF = Articulos.StockArt_A

END
GO
```

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir *no funciona*? ¿Da error? ¿Qué error? ¿No actualiza nada? ¿Has probado esa consulta fuera del TRIGGER?

Comment: Es **muy dudoso** que la tabla `Articulos` se relacione con la tabla `DetalleFacturas` por  `StockArt_A=CantArd_DF`.  A priori por la definición de la tabla debería de ser `CodArt_A`. Pero como solo has puesto la definición de una tabla y no has creado un ejemplo mínimo y verificable, pues no es más que una conjetura.